# Stop Chrome from going to a website when the connection is "not private" after using Advanced to circumvent that

Tags: google-chrome, https, ssl

I'm creating a secure website that uses HTTPS.
When Chrome accessed it, Chrome reported a "Your connection is not private" error.

[image]

I then used the "Advanced" button to go to the website anyway.

Now when Chrome goes to the website it automatically opens the page, while still reporting "Not Secure" to the left of the URL.

[image]

But I want Chrome to stop at the "Your connection is not private" error with this website.
How do I Chrome's settings to achieve this? I have tried removing all cookies for the website and modifying other security settings in Chrome. Google does not show me instructions on how to do this.

Running Chrome Version 102.0.5005.61 (Official Build) (x86_64) on a Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn warnings back on by clicking this little link in the certificate window

[image: Turn on warnings]

Comment: Thanks, Captain. How well hidden!